# Join tables with one where statement at the end or use where statement in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have the following query, which joins multiple tables each of which contains over 1 million rows:

```
Select * From TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.col1 = B.col1 
INNER JOIN TableC C ON C.col2 = B.col2
INNER JOIN TableD D ON D.col2 = C.col2
INNER JOIN TableE E ON E.col1 = B.col1 
INNER JOIN (Select * From TableF F JOIN TableG G ON F.ID=G.ID) FG 
                          ON  FG.cId = E.cId AND FG.custID = C.custID
WHERE C.ACCEPTED = 'Y'
AND D.colx IS NULL
AND D.coly IS NULL 
And D.START_DATE <= A.SD
And D.END_DATE >= A.SD
```

As this was taking too long I decided to optimise this and came up with the following:

```
Select * From TableA A
INNER JOIN TableE E ON E.col1 = A.col1 
INNER JOIN (Select * From TableF F JOIN TableG G ON F.ID=G.ID) FG 
                              ON FG.cID = C.cID AND  FG.custID = 
                                              (Select custID From 
                                   TableB B 
                                   TableC C ON C.col2 = B.col2
                                   TableD D ON D.col2 = C.col2
                                   WHERE C.ACCEPTED = 'Y'
                                   AND D.colx IS NULL
                                   AND D.colx IS NULL 
                                   And D.START_DATE <=  A.SD
                                   And D.END_DATE >=  A.SD
                                   AND B.col1 = A.col1                                                 
                                   AND rownum = 1
                                  )
```

and this improved the query but I am not sure if the two query will yield the same results (I have tested a few scenarios and results seems identical but as all tables contains millions of rows I can't go through each row and compare), and instead of joining all those tables simply getting the custId from a subquery as I did in the second one is correct?

Thanks

Comment: You have a `rownum = 1` in the second query that is not in the first.  I would assume that would make a difference.  More importantly, there is no `order by` clause, so the row being returned could even differ from one execution to the next.

Comment: Thanks, if we sort the rownum and order by issue do you think they would yield the same results?